# Domain accounts (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, domain

You know if you login to Windows 7 using your domain username and password, your password is then stored onto the local machine so that you can login next time login onto the computer if you are not connect to the network. Is there a way to store anyone's domain account's password onto Windows without the user having to logon to the computer?

Comment: Why would you store the domain's account on the computer?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: By *without the user having to logon to the computer* do you mean 1) pre-store their username/password *before they've ever logged into* the machine? or 2) Add their domain credentials to the profile, *after they've logged into it at least once before*?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. Cached credentials are stored in the user's profile on the workstation, but since in your case the user has never logged into the machine, no profile exists in which to "pre-save" their domain username or password exist.

For arguments sake, suppose you managed to pre-store their domain credentials.  When they attempted to logon the workstation without domain connectivity, the following would happen:

1. User attempts logon with domain account
2. Windows tries to contact a DC but cannot
3. Windows looks for a cached user profile on the workstation but doesn't find one
4. User is denied logon and informed *There are no logon servers available to service the logon request*

As you can see, without an already-existing user profile there's no place to store the cached credentials.